# One user profile for company and person

Tags: python, mvc, django

I'm creating a web page which has two types of users with very similar permissions: `Person` and `Company`. The main difference is in their attributes and probably different billing.

I've created only one `UserProfile` for both types of users. What do you think? Is it safe? Should I expect some problems later because of this?

The first problem I met is that I can't tell Django that if the user is a person, then username can't be blank and the same with company and `company_name`.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    TYPE_OF_USER_CHOICES = (('company', 'Company'),
                            ('person', 'Person'))

    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=TYPE_OF_USER_CHOICES)

    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)

    # PERSON

    username = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)

    # COMPANY
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)

    ICO = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, unique=True,
                           help_text=u'Zadajte firemné IČO alebo nechajte prázdne')
    DIC = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, unique=True,
                           help_text=u'Zadajte firemné DIČ alebo nechajte prázdne')

    @property
    def is_firm(self):
        return self.type_of_user == 'company'

    @property
    def is_person(self):
        return self.type_of_user == 'person'

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_firm:
            return '{} - Company'.format(self.company_name)
        else:
            return '{} - Person'.format(self.username)
```

Comment: Assumptions I would make as requirements that might affect your solution. Multiple users may belong to the same company, each user will need a different id and password. Users may change companies at some point. I can't comment on the code because I'm not an expert on mvc, django or python.

Comment: Not a proper answer as I don't have time to expand but you should look into `class Meta: abstract = True` for models. You can make an abstract `ProfileUser` model and then specialize it into `Person ` and `Company` so you can use `required = True` on the relevant fields.